# Вывод данных в template после введения в форму

Tags: python, django

```
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
    {% for field in form %}

    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field.value }}

    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Выходит такая картина:

[image]

Как вывести Form Data в template в данном случае?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите вывести. В форме пусто и выводить нечего.

Comment: Мы тебе не ответим, пока ты принт массива form не скинешь. Структуру в студию.

Comment: там в принте HTML формы будет

Comment: Массив form должен выглядеть так, чтобы заработал твой скрипт:

    form = array(
       '0' => array(
          'label_tag' => 'bla bla'
           'value' => 'bla bla'
       ),
    );
Т.е. должны быть ключи label_tag и value

Comment: Там вроде про питон вопрос)

Comment: Я понял, я передал тебе смысл, раз уж ты не можешь скинуть принт массива. Проверь, если у тебя ключи такие в массиве.

Comment: Есть у него эти ключи, глянь на картинку. Там None повыводилось. Если б ключей не было - была бы пустота.

А если вывести form на печать, там будет HTML, это не совсем массив.

А почему ничего не выводится, непонятно то ли он не отправлял форму, и тогда там и должно быть None, либо неправильно написал вьюху, которую нам не показал.

Comment: class FormAuction(FormView):
    template_name = 'last_name.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/auction/form/'

вьюха,  массив сколько ищю, нету

Comment: Form Data
csrfmiddlewaretoken:qT2jDyfuM4yyjVSB3xI9ML2mzqTk3suz
name:Ivan
last_name:Ivanov
Форма отправлена - как показывает Inspector Chrome

Comment: from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

--- forms.py

Comment: Вы после успешного сохранения формы делаете редирект на /auction/form/, после чего страница открывается по обычному GET запросу и ничего не выводит, так как ей нечего выводить.

Объясните, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: Что бы ниже была информация введенная в форму.Я в ввожу в форму name- Ivan last_name - Ivanov. ниже хочу добиться Ivan Ivanov.

Comment: Наверно, стоит что-то изменить в вьюшке, чтобы GEt запрос передавал и value полей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чтобы ниже была информация, введенная в форму. Я вввожу в форму name- Ivan last_name - Ivanov. Ниже хочу добиться Ivan Ivanov

Вопрос в том, как вы хотите этого добиться. Если просто - вывести и увидеть - то вам достаточно переопределить метод form_valid следующим образом:

```
class FormAuction(FormView):
    template_name = 'last_name.html'
    form_class = ContactForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

И ваша форма после отправки POST-запроса покажет вам то, что вы отправили. Но в этом нет никакого смысла, так как информация не сохранится.

Если же вам введенную информацию нужно сохранить и показать, смотрите [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) и [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) из того же набора, что и FormView, а также формы, построенные на основе моделей [forms.ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Comment: Спасибо, 1 вариант самое-то, да, бесмысленно, но это всё ради того, чтобы понять, как работают CBV, пока с этим туго, сейчас буду разбираться. Приятно, что есть люди, шарящие в Джанге.)